# {"error":"unauthorized"} while try to access parse dashboard

Tags: heroku, parse-platform

I had deployed parse server with parse dashboard on heroku.

Few weeks ago I was accessing dashboard without any error but now when I try to access it with

```
https://peaceful-caverns-32941.herokuapp.com/parse
```

it says `{"error":"unauthorized"}`

(I had same issue when I deployed it few weeks ago, but I didn't remember how I solved it)

whats wrong with it.

Comment: dashboard is running on port 4040 by default, also this error you posted if from Parse server and not the dashboard, i would check the configuration file for Parse dashboard (or post it here)

Comment: Run `heroku logs` when you are accessing the dashboard and post what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of the parse server require the rest and/or javascript keys to be sent if it is set on the server. So pass these in though the dashboard config:

```
  "restKey" : "xxxx",
  "javascriptKey": "xxxx",
```